# Are benders allowed to use subsets of their element's abilities in Pro-Bending?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Could the water benders use ice/snow in the tournaments? Could they use bloodbending to just push the players off the field?

Could Earthbenders use Metalbending during competition? Like the metal of the gates holding the water? Can they use the water below the field?

Could Firebenders use lightning?

Comment: Isn't bloodbending illegal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Bumi and Kya revealed + Pro Bending full rules](http://avatarthelastairbenderonline.com/bumi-kya-revealed-pro-bending/). Specifically, [the third sheet](http://avatarthelastairbenderonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Pro-Bending3.jpg) explains the rules for the specific elements.

**Could the water benders use ice/snow in the tournaments?**

No:

> Water must be used in a liquid state not as a gas or solid. So no steam, fog or ice is permitted.

**Could they use bloodbending to just push the players off the field?**

**Can they use the water below the field?**

I don't think so; no:

> Water can only be pulled from the zone lines.

**Could Earthbenders use Metalbending during competition?**

No:

> No metalbending […] is permitted, since the ring is made largely of canvas-covered metal.

**Could Firebenders use lightning?**

It doesn't seem to be prohibited anywhere in the rules.

Comment: It also specifically says in the rules that an attack should only last for 1 second, and lightning, when it strikes, lasts for more than 1 second. It lingers in the opponent's body for at least a few seconds (note Azula electrocuting Aang).

Comment: *It doesn't seem to be prohibited anywhere in the rules.* That's pretty sick, though it *may* count as a 'stream' over 1 second in duration.

Comment: Generating and redirecting lightning seem to both take a moment, during which someone can throw a rock at you which breaks your concentration and electrocutes you to death. So I'd say no against Lightningbending. And Bloodbending is illegal everywhere in Republic City, so I'm positive it's not allowed during matches.

Answer (score 3):

**No. The game seems to limit players to the elements provided on the game grid itself.** Using the basic three elements would also ensure the greatest number of potential players since the more exotic subsets would required even greater training on the part of the players and reducing the number of people able to effectively participate.

Fire-benders can produce unlimited fire so it does not need to be provided. Chunks of Earth are slotted up and are constantly renewed during a match. Water is made available from a section of the field and able to be tapped by water-benders, so there is no need to use water from below the arena.

Since the goal of the game is to push players backward from the field, it makes sense use only the most basic forms of the elements in a manner that would most effectively drive back the opposing team. Limiting the types of damage being dealt makes it possible for the uniforms being used to be able to effectively protect the players.

Professional bending is a sport designed around speed, coordination, teamwork, precision and accuracy, so using large amounts of any element which might take too long to manipulate would only make you vulnerable to attack and removal from the field. This is also true of most of the subset powers which are also equally challenging for most non-adept benders.

Comment: But to grab all the water below them and create a tidal wave to just wash the opposing team off the field seems like a good strategy lol.

Comment: Indeed it would, but I suspect trying to manipulate the water from that distance might make you too vulnerable since you would have to concentrate harder to reach it in the first place and that might keep you standing still just a bit too long. (And that might have been the reason for placing the arena that high above the water in the first place, to make it too difficult to reach.)

Answer (score 1):

Waterbenders can't use snow, steam, etc - in the rules.

Bloodbending is illegal, so it won't be allowed.

And lightning - well, none of the players seem to be allowed deadly attacks, so I doubt it - though they kind of reduced the power of lightning in LoK (as well as the level of skill required to use it - Mako is fine, but definitely not a master on the level of Iroh, Ozai or Azula)